# Gears in contact?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I was doing a practice exam paper question that was along the following lines:

> A gear, $A$,and moment of inertia $I_A$ is spinning about its axis at angular velocity $\omega$. Another gear $B$ (moment of inertia $I_B$) is brought into contact with $A$, they slip for a while then eventually lock (and therefore do not slip). Find the fractional energy change during slipping. (Both $I_A$ and $I_B$ are with respect to the centre of the respective gears)

Here is a digram of what is going on:
[image]

In the examiners report it says this question cannot be done by simple conservation of angular momentum since the two gears do not share a common axis.

I cannot see why this is the case. Angular momentum about any axis is conserved so we can take the angular about an axis through $C_A$ and get:

$$I_A \omega=I_A \theta_1 -I_B \theta_2$$

This equation can also be shown to hold true from the torque acting on the two coils. I cannot see why this cannot be done with simple conservation of angular momentum, please can you explain?

Comment: Joseph, you are correct!